# What is the mystery behind tar with (- -m) parameter?

Tags: unix

I am trying to understand why certain part of code does not work.

tar xzf - -m'

that is what makes an issue. I have tried various combinations, but without understading what does it do (excluding tar xzf itself) I cannot fix it.
I also do not know if  '- -m' the first - is some kind of error...
(Command itself is a part of bigger script, script itself is a part of a pipeline.)

```
tar: Refusing to read archive contents from terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

That is the error I get.

Comment: Probably you should begin with reading the tar manual. `man tar`

Comment: Error message is pretty clear, read manual and what option `-` does.

Answer (score 2):

`f` takes an argument, and that argument is the filename of the archive. If instead of a filename you use `-`, it means tar should read data not from a file, but from standard input. However, since in this case the standard input is the terminal, tar refuses to work.

To redirect standard input to a file, you'd use:

```
tar xzf - < archive.tar
```

The '-m' option just instructs tar to not extract the "file modification time" of the files it extracts from the archive.